# why does print vars.put ,the result is null?

Tags: jmeter

```
String pass = "123456789";
vars.put("token01",pass);
System.out.println(pass);
System.out.println(token01);
```

the result of System.out.println(pass) is right ,it is 123456789,
but the result of token01 is null, I can not understand .

Comment: What is vars? Please show the declaration

Comment: @Jens  vars - ( JMeterVariables ) - gives read/write access to variables: vars.get(key); vars.put(key,val); vars.putObject("OBJ1",new Object()); vars.getObject("OBJ2");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to access a JMeter Variable value programatically you need to consider one of the following options:

- If your variable is a String: `String value = vars.get("token01")`
- If your variable is an Object: `Object value = vars.getObject("token01")`

Demo:

[image: JMeter Variables Groovy Access]

References:

- [vars.get()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#get-java.lang.String-)
- [vars.getObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getObject-java.lang.String-)

You may also find [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use vars.get to access jmeter variables.
So you should use **System.out.println(vars.get("token01"))**. Also you can use debug sampler and view results tree combination to make sure your script is working fine [see How To Debug Your Apache Jmeter Scripts](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)
for more information on jmeter troubleshooting techniques.